# Any reason to buy Playa over the native EE relationship module?

Tags: playa, relationships

Is there any reason to buy Playa over the relationship module? I have a fairly complex relationship setup and need something to assist. Playa looks good but does it offer anything the native relationship module does not?

Comment: Playa have a Matrix integration and the nice Live Filters function. it Offers more parameters than the Relationship module.

Comment: Wait till you need help - **that's** why you buy anything from P&T!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why I buy Playa, from the [relationship field docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/relationships.html) :

> Currently it is not possible to get the parents of a relationship field that is inside of a Grid field. You can also not use Relationships inside of a Grid field that does not store Channel data.

Comment: yes the parents of a relationship is something that would be very useful to me.

Comment: I made an add-on for doing that. IMO, awesome as they were back in the day, there's now no reason to buy Playa or Matrix. https://github.com/thisisjamessmith/ee-grid-relationship-parents